# Average time from two exponential distributed arrival times

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose that the time between request arrivals at the first server is random and follows an exponential distribution with $\lambda=u_{1}$. Similarly, the time between request arrivals at the second server is also random and follows an exponential distribution with $\lambda=u_{2}$. The first server has probability $p_{1}$ of referring any request it receives to the main server, and the second server has probability $p_{2}$ of doing so. What is the average time between requests referred to the main server?

This was a MCQ and I think by exclusion the answer is $\frac{1}{u_{1} p_{1}+u_{2} p_{2}}$ but I am not sure how to derive it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should think about this problem in terms of splitting Poisson processes.

The number of requests received by the first and second server *which get referred to the main server* are $\text{Poisson}(p_1 \mu_1)$ and $\text{Poisson}(p_2 \mu_2)$, respectively. This implies the number of requests received by the main server is $\text{Poisson}(p_1\mu_1+p_2\mu_2)$ whose interarrival times are $\text{Exp}(p_1\mu_1+p_2\mu_2)$ and have mean $\frac{1}{p_1\mu_1+p_2\mu_2}$

Comment: I think there is a typo: $\text{Poisson}(p_1\mu_1+p_2\mu_2)$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming everything is independent:

- the first server is receiving requests at a rate of $u_1$ and passing on the proportion $p_1$, so is passing on requests to the central server at a rate of $u_1p_1$
- the second server is receiving requests at a rate of $u_2$ and passing on the proportion $p_2$, so is passing on requests to the central server at a rate of $u_2p_2$
- so the central server is receiving requests at a rate of  $u_1p_1+u_2p_2$, and given the memoryless property of the exponential distribution these are exponentially distributed, making the expected time between arrivals $\frac{1}{u_1p_1+u_2p_2}$